# Confusion in Overload Resolution

Tags: c++, overloading

I can't figure out how is overload resolution working here! With the first snippet it resolves to OVERLOAD A but with the second it raises an error "ambiguous call".

CODE 1

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void doThings_A(int ,int ,double){ cout<<"first fxn"<<endl;}  //OVERLOAD A
void doThings_A(int ,double,double){ cout<<"second fxn"<<endl;} //OVERLOAD B
int main() {
    // Write C code here
    doThings_A(4,5,6);

    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT FOR CODE 1: first fxn

CODE 2

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void doThings_A(double ,int ,int){ cout<<"first fxn"<<endl;}
void doThings_A(int ,double,double){ cout<<"second fxn"<<endl;}
int main() {
    // Write C code here
    doThings_A(4,5,6);

    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT FOR CODE 2:

```
error: call of overloaded 'doThings_A(int, int, int)' is ambiguous
    8 |     doThings_A(4,5,6);
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
/tmp/sI0f5j5PL7.cpp:4:6: note: candidate: 'void doThings_A(double, int, int)'
    4 | void doThings_A(double ,int ,int){ cout<<"first fxn"<<endl;}
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~
/tmp/sI0f5j5PL7.cpp:5:6: note: candidate: 'void doThings_A(int, double, double)'
    5 | void doThings_A(int ,double,double){ cout<<"second fxn"<<endl;}
```

Comment: "binding" doesn't mean what you think it does.

Comment: [Overload Resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution), Best viable function.

Answer (score 5):

A general principle of how C++ is designed in this regard (be it choosing overloads or template specializations, comparing `concept` strength, etc) is that it does **not** assign "scores" to different alternatives (based on the number of arguments requiring implicit conversions, if we're talking about function overloads, or anything else).

Instead, for A to be better than B, A has to be *not worse* in every individual aspect being compared, and also better in at least one aspect.

For function overloading, the "aspects" being compared are whether each individual argument requires an implicit conversion or not:

- In the first snippet, both overloads are equivalent with respect to arguments 1 and 3 (i.e. neither is worse than the other), but the first overload is better with respect to the argument 2. Hence the first overload is better overall.
- In the second snippet, the first overload is better with respect to arguments 2 and 3, but the second overload is better with respect to argument 1, hence the ambiguity.

---

Of course, there's more nuance to it, but the general principle still holds:

- Some implicit conversions are [better than the other](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.rank).
- If both overloads are equivalent in terms of argument conversions, overload resolution [falls back to different criteria](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best.general), but each of them follows the same principle.

Answer (score 4):

In both cases, the two overloads `doThings_A` are viable functions for the call `doThings_A(4,5,6)`, but in the first case one is a "better function" that the other.

> `F1` is determined to be a better function than `F2` if implicit conversions for all arguments of `F1` are not worse than the implicit conversions for all arguments of `F2`, and
>
> 1. there is at least one argument of `F1` whose implicit conversion is better than the corresponding implicit conversion for that argument of `F2`

---

In both cases, the worst implicit conversion (`int` to `double`) are the same, so the clause `1.` must be considered. Let's compare cases argument by argument:

```
CASE 1
           | arg1              | arg2                | arg3                |
CALL       | int               | int                 | int                 |
F1         | int (exact match) | int (exact match)   | double (conversion) |
F2         | int (exact match) | double (conversion) | double (conversion) |
WINS       | tie               | F1                  | tie                 |
```

There is at least one argument (`arg2`) whose implicit conversion is better, `F1` wins and is the best viable function.

---

```
CASE 2
           | arg1                | arg2                | arg3                |
CALL       | int                 | int                 | int                 |
F1         | double (conversion) | int (exact match)   | int (exact match)   |
F2         | int (exact match)   | double (conversion) | double (conversion) |
WINS       | F2                  | F1                  | F1                  |
```

By the same rule, both `F1` is a better viable function than `F2` (`arg2` and `arg3`) AND `F2` is a better viable function than `F1` (`arg1`). This leads to both function to rank equals, hence the ambiguous call error.

Answer (score 2):

The determining factor here is that ([Overload resolution - Best viable function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution)):

> F1 is determined to be a better function than F2 if implicit conversions for all arguments of F1 are not worse than the implicit conversions for all arguments of F2, and
>
> 1. there is at least one argument of F1 whose implicit conversion is better than the corresponding implicit conversion for that argument of F2

So lets look at the signatures:

```
void doThings_A(int ,int ,double)   // 1
void doThings_A(int ,double,double) // 2
```

When called with three `int`s, the first and third arguments are both equally good for both 1 and 2 - match and floating-point conversion respectively.

But in the second argument 1 is a match while 2 requires floating-point conversion. This means that 1 is equal or better for every argument than 2 is and so 1 is chosen.

However, in the second example we have:

```
void doThings_A(double ,int ,int)   // 3
void doThings_A(int ,double,double) // 4
```

Here 3 is a better match for the second and third argument, while 4 is a better match for the first arguments. This means that there is no candidate that is unambiguously better, and so the resolution fails.

Answer (score 2):

Overload resolution ranks the viable candidate functions by comparing how each argument of the call matches the corresponding parameter of the candidates. More importantly, for one candidate to be considered better than another, **the better candidate cannot have any of its parameters be a worse match than the corresponding parameter in the other candidate.**

Now let's apply this to each of your example snippets and see what is happening.

##### Snippet 1

```
void doThings_A(int a,int b,double c){ cout<<"first fxn"<<endl;}  //OVERLOAD A
void doThings_A(int a,double b,double c){ cout<<"second fxn"<<endl;} //OVERLOAD B
int main() {
    // Write C code here
    doThings_A(4,5,6);

    return 0;
}
```

Now for the first overload `doThings_A(int ,int ,double)`, the call `doThings(4,5,6)` has first two arguments `4` and `5` which matches exactly with the corresponding first two parameters(`a` and `b` respectively) while the third argument `6` requires a conversion to `double` which is also required for the third parameter of the second overload. In other words, *the first candidate does not have any parameter that is a worse match than the corresponding parameter in the second candidate.*

On the other hand, *the second parameter of the second overload* `void doThings_A(int ,double,double)` *is a worse match than the corresponding second parameter of the first overload* `void doThings_A(int ,int ,double)`. Hence the second overload cannot be a better candidate than the first candidate.

In conclusion, the first candidate is better match than the second candidate.

---

##### Snippet 2

```
void doThings_A(double ,int ,int){ cout<<"first fxn"<<endl;}
void doThings_A(int ,double,double){ cout<<"second fxn"<<endl;}
int main() {
    // Write C code here
    doThings_A(4,5,6);

    return 0;
}
```

In this case, the first overload `void doThings_A(double ,int ,int)` has the first parameter that is a worse match than the corresponding first parameter of the second overload `void doThings_A(int a,double b,double c)` so the first overload cannot be a better candidate as per the highlighted part at the beginning.

Similarly, the second overload `void doThings_A(int a,double a,double a)` has the second and third parameters which are worse match than the corresponding second and third parameters of the first overload `void doThings_A(double ,int ,int)`. Thus the second candidate cannot be a better candidate than the first.

Hence in this case neither is better than other and the call is ambigious.